# ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Tags: javascript, import, module

using Node.js I installed the JSHint package and wrote the following options in the .jshintrc file:

```
{
"version": 9,
"camelcase": false,
"undef": true,
"unused": false,
   "global": {
     "window": true
   }
}
```

Next I run build task within gulpfile.js

```
function lint_client() {
    return src('./client/js/Controller_ui.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
}

function browserify_client() {
    return src('./client/js/Controller_ui.js')
        .pipe(browserify({
            insertGlobals: true
        }))
        .pipe(rename('Controller_ui.js'))
        .pipe(dest('./public'));
}

exports.build = series(lint_client, browserify_client);
```

Above COntrollef_ui.js file content is:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$(window).ready(function(){
    console.log('äö');
});
```

and the message with the problem I have, is in the console:

```
/workspace/deploy-contracts/client/js/fake_f2c8a270.js:2
import $ from 'jquery';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

or

```
/workspace/deploy-contracts/client/js/fake_f2c8a270.js:2
import { $ } from 'jquery';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

Is it about the `top level` of a tree or do I not understand? How to solve or delete the error?

Comment: Is your bundler also including a `<script>` tag with a `require()` statement in your bundled `index.html` file that brings in jQuery? If so, you do not need the `import` statement.

Comment: No, is a  ´SyntaxError in plugin 'gulp-browserify'´ and I must use JSHint to parse before transpiling. Has nothing to do with script tags in client page

Comment: You were not specific about your build system. If nothing in the HTML file then it doesn't appear you are using Babel? Browserify only understands CommonJS - you must use a transcoder to modify your ES6 module syntax.

Comment: I don't know the difference very well. However, I did some research on this. I have the gulp file as I told you, the node_module dependencies and the express server. I try to use node_modules on the browser side but they must be somewhat independent of the server.

Comment: I use nodemon in the development not Babel

Comment: consider this: "_https://github.com/browserify/browserify/graphs/code-frequency_" - focus on the 2018 and beyond. Then consider replacing browserify with [rollupjs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) or something similar. Read the docs on rollup. it will make your life easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240241/discussion-between-robert-dan-and-randy-casburn).